# How to automatically update references automatically in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

How can we go forth to change the settings so that when we change the name of a variable/method, the references of these variable/method will automatically change? Is there any setting or plugin which can do such in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure if this is what you are after, but if by reference you mean wherever in your code you are referring to this method or variable. try Alt+F7 (if you're on Mac, you might have to go Fn+Alt+F7) on your method, variable or class name to find all the references.

If you want to change (rename) every reference in your code, you just press shift+F6 and then start typing the new name, enter when you are done. This will change every reference to your method or variable.

Works on both IntelliJ and Android Studio, even AppCode.